# Change color of done button in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, wkwebview, uitoolbar

I use this code in appDelegate to change color of all UIBarButtonItem of my navigationBar in my project to white

```
let whiteAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)! ,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(whiteAttr, for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(whiteAttr, for: .highlighted)
```

But Done button of my ToolBar in WKWebView is also white, how can i change the color ?

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working using the appearance APIs from iOS 13:

```
let doneButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
doneButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]

let toolBarAppearance = UIToolbarAppearance()
toolBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance = doneButtonAppearance

UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolBarAppearance
// Unsure if this is needed
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolBarAppearance
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
```

Comment: To my inexpert eye that looks pretty similar to the OP's code - setting a foregroundColor attribute in the same way, just not at the same time as the font. Is that the crucial difference? Can you add some explanation please?